# Copy UV maps to mesh

Tags: uv

I want to copy a UV map from one mesh to another mesh.

I tried the "Link Object Data" > "Transfer UV Maps" approach, but that overwrites the previous UV map.

I also tried copy-pasting the UV map like it is described here:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/uv/magic_uv.html

The UV islands looks similar but they are positioned in the wrong way and too big.

How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Is there anyone who can help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We have two objects with the same topology, but different UV maps.  Both are named "UVMap" and there are no other UV maps on either object:

[image]

We want to copy the UV map from one object to the other, and we also want to retain our original UV map.

1. In object mode, select your "destination" object, the object that you wish to copy UVs onto.  Add a new UV map to it by clicking the + button on properties/object data/UV maps.  The second UV map, "UV.001", will be selected.
2. Enter object mode.  Shift select your "source" object in the 3D viewport.  "Copy UV Maps" operation, which I'd access via ctrl L link/transfer data menu.

Your destination now has two UV maps.  One, "UVMap", contains its original UV.  The other, "UVMap.001", contains the UV of the destination object.

Comment: It says: Object has 38145 loops (for 12715 faces), expected 28394

Comment: @ABren Then they don't have the same topology, and you cannot copy UV maps easily or perfectly from one mesh to the other.  Any solution will involve manual editing and fixes.